# Applying Date Pipe on Dynamic Angular Table

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-table, date-pipe

My "data" object looks like

```
[
 {"id": "abc001", "lastInspectionDate": "2019-09-26T00:00:00.000Z", "nextInspectionDate": "2021-09-26T00:00:00.000Z"},
 {"id": "abc002", "lastInspectionDate":"2018-08-25T00:00:00.000Z",  "nextInspectionDate": "2020-08-25T00:00:00.000Z"}
]
```

I want to display the data in a dynamic table. Below are my HTML code.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mt-2 mat-elevation-z0">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let column of allCols" [matColumnDef]="column">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ column }}</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
         {{ column['lastInspectionDate'] ? (row[column]| date: 'mediumDate') : row[column] }}
      </td>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

This is my ts codes where I define the dataSource for the table.

```
this.dataSource.data = data;
this.pageSize = data.length;
let headers = Object.keys(data[0]);
this.allCols = headers;
```

My conditional pipe for the date is not working. Can you guys help me or give me another kind of solution? I've been stucked at this for a week. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you checked the value of column['Last Inspection Date'] in the debugger? What does it contain? Shouldn't it be column['lastInspectionDate']?

Comment: Oh yes, i just noticed the mistake. Already edited the question. But it still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try this :

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mt-2 mat-elevation-z0">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let column of allCols" [matColumnDef]="column">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ column }}</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
         {{ column === 'lastInspectionDate' ? (row[column]| date: 'mediumDate') : row[column] }}
      </td>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

Comment: This is basically what I meant by my comment. Good to know it worked tho :)